# How to dynamically add "hidden" field to form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use OptimizePress (wordpress theme).  It has great opt-in forms but unfortunately, there isn't a way to add a hidden form field through their UI.  I do have the option to add custom scripts for each page.

How can I dynamically add a predefined hidden field to a form?  The form does not have an ID.  Something like the following may work but how can it be done when there is no form ID?

```
var input = document.createElement("input");

input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

input.setAttribute("name", "name_you_want");

input.setAttribute("value", "value_you_want");

//append to form element that you want .
document.getElementById("formname").appendChild(input);
```

This is the only form on the page.

Using some of the examples below, it doesn't work with type=hidden: https://jsfiddle.net/eLazhj3d/1.

But works with type=text: https://jsfiddle.net/eLazhj3d/2.

Comment: Is there only one form in the page?

Comment: yes - just one form.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working fiddle (with a visible text field to show):

Using:

```
document.querySelector("form").appendChild(input);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s55snxtn/

Code:
**html:**

```
<form action=""><input type="text"/>
</form>
```

**javascript:**

```
var input = document.createElement("input");

input.setAttribute("type", "text");

input.setAttribute("name", "name_you_want");

input.setAttribute("value", "value_you_want");

//append to form element that you want .
document.querySelector("form").appendChild(input);
```

Comment: I get this error: [Error] NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.
 appendChild (mysite.com, line 22)
 onload (mysite.com, line 22)

Comment: That's weird, can you try it with this: document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].appendChild(input); if it doesn't work, can you please post the corresponding code incl. html form?

Comment: still no good.  I can't post the code because it is a huge amount.  It's wordpress.

Comment: Sorry, been not at the computer... Sorry for the stupid question, but did you try it with a submission as you don't see the hidden input...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eLazhj3d/5/ works perfectly, tried it locally, field is just hidden

Comment: Why would it be hidden?  I did try it in a real form.  I'm not seeing the field come through.  I should be in the form, just like the text field is.  Something about "hidden" that is making this not work.

Comment: You wanted a hidden field, didn't you? From your question: "How can I dynamically add a predefined hidden field to a form?"

Comment: input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Add hidden form field into a form dynamically. Isn't that what we've been trying to do?  You said it works locally.  What makes you say that?  Do you see the field has been added?  Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Of course you don't see that it is added, because hidden fields are invisible. But if you submit the form and try to catch it's value on the next page, you can get it's value - in this case 'home'

Comment: Hidden form fields are not invisible. They just don't appear in the UI where a user can see them.  Like I said, I've tried this on a real form and the field value does not come through.

Comment: :) I tried it too, I could fetch the data with php $_POST.... That's weird. What did you do to fetch it. --- I meant invisible for the viewer...

Comment: fetch it?  I just add the script to the OptimizePress page.  I can see it in the head section of the rendered page.  So that part works at least.  This is going into a MailChimp form.  I submit the form but don't see the field come through in MailChimp?  If the field is there statically, it does come through.

Comment: I'm not fully aware of how MailChimp handles $_POST data, but if you simply try to fetch $_POST['signupform'] in your next page (after the form), I'm sure you get the value. (F.E. simple do "echo $_POST['signupform'];" -- the output will be "home" if you left all the fields as in the fiddle

Comment: One other way is to mark the field as "text".  Then put it into a div with display:none.  Then add the div to the form.

Comment: It is, yes. But I can't imagine a way this should work while the hidden way would not - or oposite

Comment: Looks like maybe some weirdness going on with Mailchimp.  It will take a little time to confirm with them. I'll post back what happens.

Comment: I'll be happy to hear!

Answer (score 1):

Using the `document.querySelector()` function you can target any element using a css selector base, so in your case:

```
document.querySelector("form").appendChild(input);
```

Would get any element that is a `form` tag.

[**Query Selector Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector)

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one form tag in the page, you can use

```
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
```

It will return an array, just get the element in the first index

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery

```
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'foo',
    name: 'bar',
    value: 'value'
}).appendTo('form');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
document.forms[0].appendChild(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getElementsByTagName which returns an array.

If it's the first form on the page would be something like

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].appendChild(input);
```